# How to get a handle on logged in username for sql parameter in datasource control properties select query

Tags: c#, asp.net, membership

I can get a handle on the logged in user for a label object with Membership.GetUser().UserName;. But in the properties window for a datasource control object, for the select query property, i want to set a sql parameter property to the logged in username.

I tried System.Web.Security.Membership.GetUser().UserName, to no avail.

Frankly, im not actually sure how to set a value to the parameters when using the datasource control. this is done in the markup for the web page, not the c# programming code and i feel kind of in the dark.

This is the data source object. The params are there, but i have no idea how to actually use them

You can see that i have pulled the name from a label which i mentioned above. obviously this is not hte way to do it, and does not help at all when trying to update the data. (which gives me another problem where it will update every row, but i can deal with that once i can actually update.)

```
<asp:SqlDataSource 
    ID="SqlDataSource1" 
    runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Warren_SEINDATASYSTEMSConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT [VisitorCode], [VisitorName] FROM [RegisteredVisitors] WHERE [ResidentName] = @ResidentName" 
    UpdateCommand="UPDATE [dbo].[RegisteredVisitors] SET [VisitorCode] = '3222' ,[VisitorName] = @VisitorName WHERE [ResidentName] = @ResidentName"> 

    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="Label1" DefaultValue="none" Name="ResidentName" PropertyName="Text" />
    </SelectParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="Label1" Name="VisitorName" PropertyName="Text" />
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="GridView1" Name="ResidentName" PropertyName="" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: can you show us your code in full for what you have tried

Comment: Iv updated the post. it's basically the datasource object. but as mentioned, i can't figure out how to actually use the params correctly.

Comment: is there any specific reason why you're doing this in the aspx page rather than in the code behind?   and which parameter should be the user name?

Comment: What handle wouldni usebtobdocit in the code behind? That would be a lot easier

Comment: My phone keyboard sucks. What handler would I use, that would be much easier to do.